# Process Nested HashMaps with List of Integers in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, flatmap

I want to do a simple Operation in Java 8. Below is the code

```java
List<Integer> lst =  Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
Map<String,List> inner = new HashMap<String,List>();
inner.put("first",lst);

Map<String,Map<String,List>> outer =
  new HashMap<String,Map<String,List>>();
outer.put("Bigger",inner);
```

What I want to do is , return boolean if all the values in a child map List of Integers satisfy a criteria

I tried to do below but it seems it is not working :

```java
boolean lessThanfiveAll =
  outer.entrySet().stream().flatMap(
    e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream().flatMap(
      v -> v.getValue().stream().allMatch(e -> e < 5)));
```

The issue arises at `v ->v.getValue().stream().allMatch`
The value inside allMatch is not considered as an Integer and I get compiler error as `operator < cannot be applied to java.lang.Object`

Can anybody please help here ?

Comment: `Map<String,List>` should be `Map<String,List<Integer>>` (or simply `var`) and `Map<String,Map<String,List>>` should be `Map<String,Map<String,List<Integer>>>`. You're [using a raw type `List`, which you should not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Comment: As Joachim Sauer said, don’t use raw types. After you fixed the types, you can use, e.g. `boolean lessThanfiveAll = outer.values().stream() .flatMap(m -> m.values().stream()) .flatMap(List::stream) .allMatch(i -> i < 5);`

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use `flatMap`. Would this work?

`boolean lessThanfiveAll = outer.entrySet().stream().allMatch(e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream().allMatch(v ->v.getValue().stream().allMatch(e1 -> e1 < 5)));`